# make VScode auto highlight .txt files as Markdown

Tags: markdown, visual-studio-code

Found this very helpful in Notepad++, but can't find the option to do it in VSCODE, Could VSCODE do it? Looking around setting for a while and Googled but nothing help.

EDIT: I know that I could easily make vscode highlight my txt file content by `F1/Change Language Mode/json` but I wonder how to make it `auto-highlight txt file content as markdown syntax`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In VSC you can change the syntax-highlighting from 'Plain-text' to another 'language' by clicking the 'Plain-text'-button on the bottom right of the window.

edit:
You can make VCS always do `.md` syntax-highligting on `.txt` files doing:
-> Press`F1`
-> Type in `Change Language Mode`
-> Choose `Configure File Association for '.txt'`
-> Choose `Markdown`

Comment: thanks for reply, i've update my question to be clearer.