Coloring comments in .txt for vscode
I want to highlight my "#-like" comments in .txt files in Visual Studio Code. What settings or extensions can help me with that? Thanks for answer
enter image description here
Tried to download random extensions in VSC extension's store, but they're just ignoring # comments.

Just plain txt, or txt containing some commonly known format?

Here is the documentation if you want to do it from scratch: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide

For sure, txt is used by Clausewitz Engine in some mod files. Game engine has it's own syntax, so I think we're need to talk just about plain txt.

@EugeneSh. If I understand correctly, this is documentation on how to create your own syntax extension. Is there an easier way for me (since my needs are limited to highlighting # of comments), or is this the best there is?

You could hijack some existing syntax with similar comment style (like Makefile for example. But it will also highlight unrelated items, which are part of that syntax. (this is how you can make VSCode to treat txt as some "language": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56929986/make-vscode-auto-highlight-txt-files-as-markdown )

@EugeneSh. Thanks, that's helped me!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Use the extension Highlight, you define some regex and colors
